# Variable enters C function as nonzero, turns to zero inside by itself

Tags: c

I'm debugging a piece of code and found that when I print out a variable prior to function execution it is nonzero. The same variable is then used as an input argument for a function, but when printing it out right at the beginning of that function it says it's zero.

Outside the function call it looks like this:

```
printf("sigma_b_m: %f \n",sigma_b_m);
oprq_init(sigma_b_m, b_m, r_m, x, P);
```

Inside the function call I did the following:

```
void oprq_init(const float sigma_b_m, const float b[3], const float r[3], float K[16], float P[256]) {`
    printf("sigma_b_m: %f \n",sigma_b_m);
}
```

I removed the rest of the function for clarity but the printf line is really at the very start of the function.

The output is then:

> sigma_b_m: 0.001745
>   sigma_b_m: 0.000000

Any idea how it now registers as zero rather than the 0.001745 it told me it was prior to going into the function?

Comment: Show the function's prototype, and also enough code to actually see the full picture.

Comment: Not possible to answer.

Comment: Did you declare the function before calling it?  If not, your float will be promoted to double.

Comment: Show the reproducing code

Comment: @unwind I don't know what more could be relevant? In my full code absolutely nothing comes in between both printf statements.

Comment: @TomKarzes Do you mean what's in my header file? It's only:

extern void oprq_init(const float sigma_b_m, const float b[3], const float r[3], float K[16], float P[256]);

Comment: And you're including the header file in the file that makes the call, right?

Comment: @Omnia87 The function's prototype and the call can be relevant, which is why I asked. Notice lots of other comments with the same idea.

Comment: How I call the function is in the first code segment and the prototype I just commented to Tom Karzes.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes the header file is called there.

Comment: In that case I don't know what else to suggest without seeing a more complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I realized my own dumb mistake... the header file had a typo in the `#ifndef` statement... I'm sorry for the trouble guys and my obstinacy.